# Still Getting error "Can not do this to a protected sheet" even though macro is working properly?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

So I thought I was finished with this code and it was working but when I navigate away from Sheet 1 to any other sheet and then back to sheet 1 A msgbox pops up and informs me that I can't do that to a protected sheet.

I am unclear as to why this is happening as the code is doing exactly what it is supposed to... Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I probably should have mentioned that the Sheet is protected with the password "1". I realize this is not the most appropriate password, it is more for ease of access while I work through this problem.

```
Sub freezesheet()
'set variable for the naming of the new sheet
Dim newname As String

'assignes our open variable to a designated value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
newname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value

'copies the sheet to a new sheet after the designated tab
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Sheets(3)
ActiveSheet.Name = newname

'unprotects the sheet so we can copy and paste as values
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "1"

'makes all of the formulas on the sheets into values and returns you to the original sheet
Cells.Select
    selection.Copy
    selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Re-protects sheet to ensure that we don't make changes to historical data.
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do this twice, it will try to rename the sheet to `newname` (the value in C2), when that sheet name would already by taken?

Comment: Good point, This is an issue that I have already dealt with with this tool. The value in cell C2 gets changed by the user before each instance of running the macro.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, but I'm not explicitly sure what your problem is. You say this happens when you go back to sheet1, is this sub triggered by a sheet change event?

Comment: @Wolfie No, that's what is weird. I have it set to a button. I've made some changes base on your code below, which I very much appreciate. I think I have one question, posted below about the check on if there is already a sheet with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below re-write cleans up a few things. Hopefully with those taken care of, the sub should run without error. Namely:

- Checks for existing sheet with same name to avoid potential clash
- Uses `.Value` to avoid putting large amount of data in the clipboard
- Avoids Selecting and Activating when not necessary
- Fully qualifies ranges using `ThisWorkbook`

See comments for details

```
Sub freezesheet()
    'set variable for the naming of the new sheet
    Dim newname As String
    'assigns newname variable to a designated value
    newname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
    ' Check if sheet name already exists
    Dim sh as worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(newname)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not sh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error: sheet name already exists, aborted"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'copies the sheet to a new sheet after sheet 3
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Sheets(3)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
        .Name = newname ' New sheet was after sheet 3, so now sheet 4
        'unprotects the sheet so we can copy and paste as values
        .Unprotect "1"
        'makes all of the formulas on the sheets into values
        .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
        'Re-protects sheet to ensure that we don't make changes to historical data.
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
                , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't
    `If sh Is Nothing then`
include some kind of indicator for not? If sh is nothing says that there isn't a worksheet with the same name, so the code should continue right? It should end if sh is not nothing?

Comment: Yes @DataNinja, you are right! My mistake, I didn't test the above code. I have corrected the mistake in an edit.

Comment: I can confirm, This works Perfectly. Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: For future continuity as well, I will add, the error was coming back to a protected sheet and trying to select the object (Prohibited by the protection). I just added `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).range("C2").Select`after to circumvent that issue.